# ModuleNotFoundError 'mediapipe'

Tags: macos, mediapipe

I have been trying to install mediapipe on my M2 Pro Mac but have not had any success since weeks now. I have followed the guide found on https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install#installing_on_macos .

As soon as I run the line `import mediapipe as md` in VS Code I receive the error message:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'mediapipe'
File "/Users/bahir/Desktop/Python Lessons/import cv2.py", line 2, in 
import mediapipe as md
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe'

I installed and updated my mediapipe library using pip3 aswell as homebrew. It shows up as installed when trying to reinstall mediapipe using pip3 but it vscode cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

By uninstalling and then reinstalling media pipe worked in my case. I have created a virtual environment for installing media pipe and by activating, it worked.